# Explicit bounds of the error in Stone weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

In my research I would like to approximate uniformely a function $f: [a,b] \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ by polynomials (where $f$ is typically $C^1$). If the Stone-Weierstrass gives a density result for arbitrarly big polynomials, for my problem I would in fact need a bound on the error at a finite step (when the polynomials available can't be too big).

To be more concret I would like to have an inequality of the type $$\underset{(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}},\sum_{k=0}^\infty |k a_k| < \alpha}{\inf}||f-\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k X^k||_{\infty}\leq \frac{C}{\alpha^n}$$  (where $n>0$ and $C$ is a constant that depend of $||f||_\infty$ and $||\nabla f||_\infty$ but not of $\alpha$).

So I would like to know if there is a theorem which proove this kind of result (or a close one) in the literature.

Comment: Do you really want a series inside the norm or just a finite sum, i.e. a polynomial?

Comment: Jackson's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality) might come close to what you are looking for.
I'm pretty sure that there are versions of this Theorem that deal with algebraic polynomials instead of trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link toward the Jackson's theorem, it is quite close of what I need. The variants for this theorem seems to be call "Jackson-type theorem" so I will look if I find what I need (the theorem for algebraic polynomials and with boundness on the coefficients). Now that I have the key-word, it will be much easier for me to find references.